# How do I change the style of a tab control after it has been created?

Tags: c++, powerbuilder, windows-controls

I have a Windows form (*not* a WPF form) that contains a tab control from CommCtrl.h. According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I should be able to change the "style" to TCS_BUTTONS after the control has been created. Unfortunately, I can't find any examples on how to do that. Can anyone provide a reference to C++ or VB6 code to do this?

More specifically, I'm using PowerBuilder 11.5 which wraps the native MS tab control. PowerBuilder doesn't expose the TCS_BUTTONS style but I'm looking for a way to send the raw messages to change the style anyway to get around this PowerBuilder limitation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the PowerBuilder angle but if you want to add a flag in the style of a control try this:

```
DWORD dwStyle = ::GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
dwStyle |= TCS_BUTTONS;

::SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, dwStyle);
```

You can use the same sort of concept to remove a style, e.g.

```
dwStyle &= ~dwRemove;
```

Comment: PowerBuilder doesn't have bitwise operators :( and doesn't define WinAPI constants automatically. I came up with GWL_STYLE = -16 and TCS_BUTTONS = 256. And dwStyle += TCS_BUTTONS. Unfortunately, I'm not seeing any change.

Comment: Using Spy++ what style does the PowerBuilder control have?

Comment: Window 00040BAE "" PBTabControl32_100 ---- That *should* be a subclass of the standard MS control, but I don't know how to verify that.